# Is saturation region defined for a "given" collector emitter voltage?

Tags: transistors, npn, semiconductors, solid-state-devices

I have seen the traditonal saturation regions graphs (attached). The graph gives the impression that there is a huge region which is saturation region. Shouln't the saturation region be for a "given Vce".

For example: For the given transitor, for a given Vce, you can increase the Ib and Ic will increase but it will stop increasing beyond certain Ib when we will get the max Ic for that Vce.  But now if you increase the Vce for the same transsitor, you can increaee Ib more than previous case and Ic will increase too.

So shouldnt the Saturation region be Vce dependant instead of a huge region on left of active region.?[image]

Comment: Sometimes yes, saturation is defined as Vce<= 0.2V. Read your transisthor's datasheet, it may use a different definition.

Comment: Your argument seems to be that "*for a fixed VCE, current should increase till the point marked `A`. Collector current wont increase further. So saturation "region" for a given VCE is a "point", not a region.*" Is the above interpretation of your question correct?

Comment: Yes and that point depends on Vce. So same transistor can have lower or higher point A based on Vce

Comment: The point of quantifying saturation, is that the Q point in that diagram is an operating condition in the middle of a range of good transistor gain.   Details about the nonlinear (saturation) part of the curve are rarely as useful.

Comment: See if figure 8-12 and following paragraphs of [this pdf](https://www.chu.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Chenming-Hu_ch8-2.pdf#page=15) answer your question. You may also take a look at [the equation for Ic in the Ebers-Moll model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Ebers%E2%80%93Moll_model) and see if that answers your question. The basic point seems to be that, the base current also (directly) contributes to the collector current when the BJT is in saturation (i.e., CB junction in forward biased.)

Answer (score 1):

> But now if you increase the Vce for the same transsitor, you can increaee Ib more than previous case and Ic will increase too.

You cannot directly increase Vce; you can increase Vcc. After that, you really "can increase Ib more than previous case and Ic will increase too".

In this graphical representation, you can change Ib, Vcc and Rc; as a result, Ic and Vce will change.

The saturation voltage Vce(sat) is (slightly) Vcc and Rc dependent but it does not depend on Ib.